# How to save captured image in savedinstance so that I can retreive back after orientation

Tags: android

Below code captures image using camera and displays in activity, when orientation changes, I lose image captured, how can i retrieve image back after orientation, how to save the image in savedinstance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //Bitmap photo = ImageUtils.getInstant().getCompressedBitmap("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you can retrieve the path of the picture from phone or simply save the bitmap in file system before orientation change. Store the path in bundle and then in onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) set the image to image view.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
                super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
                 if(photo!=null)
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
  }


     Bitmap photo;// move to member variable


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               // photo is member variable
                photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                //Bitmap photo = ImageUtils.getInstant().getCompressedBitmap("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);


            }
        }
```

Comment: Nop, already tried, this doesn't work. When orientation changes, it vanishes. This happens mostly with Samsung devices where it captures in landscape